# Delphi High-DPI Components

Tags: delphi, highdpi

I've a question about High-DPI application in Delphi.
Surfing on the Internet I've found a series of articles published by Žarko Gajić. these articles speaks about create Delphi application ready for High-DPI.
The method describes works fine but, the author use it inside every single application; for example speaking about TSpeedButtons.

My question is this: there is a way to implement this kind of behaviour also into components? For example I'm realising a simple component that works like the Embarcadero TSpeedButton but using Transparent PNG images.
The images inside the component are loaded at design-time from some PNG images. I've a TObjectDictionary in which I register the buttons states: enabled, disabled and so on.It is declared in this way:

```
FGlyphs: TObjectDictionary<TGlyphState, TPicture>
```

In the application that use this component I load PNG images from the files that are 24 x 24 pixel. When I execute the application on a 4K monitor this images become very small. 
If I apply the Žarko method all works well but in this way every application the use my component need to implement this solution.

How to implement it directly inside the component? I thought to implement it inside the *SetGlyph* procedure, that is like the following code, but I don't know if this is the right place.

```
procedure TNCRSpeedButton.SetGlyphs(Index: TGlyphState; Value: TPicture);
begin
  FGlyphs.Items[Index].Assign(Value);
end;
```

TGlyphState is defined in this way:

```
TGlyphState = (gtEnabled, gtDisabled, gtDown, gtOver);
```

Eros

Comment: High-DPI awareness is dependent on each individual application and not on each individual component. You can not have High-DPI aware component if the application doesn't support High-DPI awareness.

Answer (score -1):

1) First of all you should enable option `Enable High-Dpi` in `Project Option -> Application -> your target platform -> Manifest file`. This option is available since Delphi 10 (Seattle).

2) if in W10 OS you have different `Scale`, you could calculate and run `TWinControl.ScaleBy` (available for Forms) for adjust window and all elements on one specific window.

See demo on https://github.com/KohrAhr/DelphiDemoPPI

Demo contain `TToolButtons` controls.